# Calculate consistency of binary responses

Tags: descriptive-statistics, similarities, diversity

I have a set of question's responses (R) from users (U) that have binary values = {pertinent, not-pertinent}, as shown in the next example:

```
       R1          R2           ...    Rn          
U1 : pertinent,   pertinent      ...    not-pertinent
U2 : pertinent,   not-pertinent  ...    pertinent
..
Um:  pertinent,   pertinent       ...    pertinent
```

I've 10 questions each question have 10 responses from 10 users.

What statistical approach that I should use in order to quantify the consistency (i.e whether the the degree of consensus in user responses is high or not.)of user responses ?

Comment: Can you give some more information?  Do you have some other variables? Sample size? And what do you mean by "consistency of user responses"?

Comment: Consistency means whether the the degree of consensus in user responses is high or not. 
I've 10 questions each question have 10 responses from 10 users.

Comment: Please add that new information to the original post, that is the expectation in here!  You can edit your own post.

Comment: Done.
Have you any suggestion about the suitable method to use ?